# How can I use Reflection in C# to gather information from unmanaged assemblies written in C++/VB?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, unmanaged

I have a project I'm working on in which I parse a .vbp file which contains a list of paths to assemblies and their GUID's (along with other things). The goal in parsing the file is to use the full path of each assembly to load them, and then use Reflection to get information about each assembly such as its interfaces and the methods and properties they define.

Now the code I have so far works just fine on *managed* assemblies (such as a .exe written in C#), however all of these assemblies that are being loaded are *unmanaged* C++/VB assemblies. When I try calling:

```
var assemblyPath = @"C:\*path to unmanaged .dll*";
var assemblyObj = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

on the unmanaged assemblies, I get a BadImageFormat exception, which is expected since it isn't a managed assembly. I've looked all over for how to go about this but most of the information I've found so far has been asking about actually using the things defined in unmanaged assemblies. In these instances, the solution required knowing information such as the name of a function the User was trying to get from the unmanaged assembly to utilize in their managed application. The only things I know about the assemblies are their paths, names, and that they're unmanaged C++/VB. I don't need to call any functions or *use* anything from these assemblies, I just need to obtain their information such as the names of their defined interfaces and the signatures of the methods within those interfaces.

Two pages I've found that looked promising are:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ch59zxfc(v=vs.90).aspx

While I've looked through these, I can't claim to be well-versed in Reflection, or even .NET, and as such I'm not really sure what I should be going with/how to implement what I'm trying to do.

Comment: sorry to say but reflection works only on the managed code ...

Comment: There's an old tool called DUMPBIN that lets you do quite a bit of lurking inside an unamanged executable, but it's not a programmatic interface. It might *leverage* some existing interfaces you could try once you determine a given exe isn't managed.

Comment: @PranayRana I understand that reflection only works on managed code, however is there a way to apply some sort of wrapper around unmanaged code to make it "appear" to be managed?

Comment: I guess a way to put it would be whereas Platform Invoke allows managed code access to functions in unmanaged assemblies given the function signature is redeclared in the managed code, what I'm looking for is a way just to get a string representing the signature in the unmanaged code, given the name of the assembly (So I don't even need the functionality that P/Invoke allows, just what gets supplied to it).

Comment: Can't be done. The only place that info would be available is in the debug information or in the original source. Native code has no concept of signature, only of a symbol name. The caller is expected to know the signature. Now if it is C++, the symbol name may be mangled to include the signature, but anything beyond that is unlikely. The other option is to disassemble the function in a manner similar to IDA Pro or some other tool like that, but even that is imperfect and definitely not trivial.